# Any one having good link or blogs to go through xcom functionality in apache airflow,

Tags: python, airflow

I m facing issues in key and value in xcom. How to call that and assign to push and pull.

step 1: I  need to get value from mongodb collection and send that file present in the collection to server's local folder and change the file status to inprogress

step 2: Need to load that downloaded file to mysql

step 3: Change the status of the file to success/ failure in the mongodb

I m done with first 2 steps..pending with step 3...how to get back to the previous task (step :1) and change the status to success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could go through the official documentation thats the best source - [here](http://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html)
2. They  also have their GitHub repository, but for your case I think you should check this sample code [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py)
   Also for more help you could check out their complete [airflow repo](https://github.com/apache/airflow)

Comment: I m going through those links. Thank you

Comment: when i assign some value as global i can pull that value, but when i assign that value inside one function i cant pull that value..plz explain

Comment: A value declared inside a function's scope limits only to the function so you cannot access it outside the function.

Comment: then, xcom is the one which acts as cross communication right? i want to access the variables which I used in the other function ,what I have to do then?